# admin username changed, now can't access website

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

im in no way a coder, and have inherited a cPanel server, with many sites on it... one of our sites, is constantly needing stuff done, but we have had no documentation at all to work from.  We don't even have the admin creds to log into the site.  So in cPanel, there is 1 database, and 1 user.  So it was thought, that the database user was the admin user.  So the password was changed, and as soon as that was done, no access to the site anymore, we get an error now when launching the URL

error: 
Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/pheamlam/public_html/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 336

URL:
http://testing.phe-aml.com/login/index.php

At this point, I'm not interested in spending hours and hours learning php or MySQL, but would like to overcome this issue.

Any ideas or suggestions?  Feel free to let me know of some options, I'm just not sure where to go or what to do to resolve this and move on....

Thanks, and have a great day!

Comment: *"At this point, I'm not interested in spending hours and hours learning php or MySQL, but would like to overcome this issue."* - So post your code. We'd only be doing the same guessing what you're using for code. Did you Google that error? That URL won't do any good.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not debuggers-for-hire.

Comment: Kind of a long shot but maybe whoever made this site hardcoded in the username and password into the connection string? Thus when the password changed there is a mismatch and it can no longer validly authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to cpanel, open the file manager

Go to this directory `/home/pheamlam/public_html/`

Open this file `config.php`

These are the database details

```
$CFG->dbuser    = 'databaseuser';
$CFG->dbname    = 'databasebame';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'xxxxxxxx';
```

UPDATE:

There will probably be a username called `admin`, you can change the password using SQL.

So go to the cpanel, go to phpmyadmin, click on the moodle database, click on the SQL tab.

Then enter the following to change the password for the admin user.

```
UPDATE mdl_user
SET password = md5('newpassword')
WHERE username = 'admin'
```

Then you can login as admin and the newpassword.

Comment: You sir, are fantastic...  exactly what I wanted, and delivered in perfect fashion... Thank you.

Comment: Now... my previous admin didn't document any passwords, so how would one be able to gain access to the admin side of that site??  *another thread?*

Comment: Updated the answer to change the admin password.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Moodle code. The error probably means that the database connection details in the file /home/pheamlam/public_html/config.php no longer match the correct settings to access your database.

Open up that file and enter the new username + password for accessing your mysql database and your site should start working again.